# Woocommerce: Run PHP function on cart update

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to display a message on my WooCommerce Cart Page, that tells my customers, how much they need to purchase to get a free gift.

I already got the following code which works, but I have one problem.

When customers update their cart or the quantity the following code does not update (*because the page does not reload*).

```
    <?php $e_cart = WC()->cart->cart_contents_total * 1.25;?>
    <?php $e_cart_remaining = 300 - $e_cart; ?>

    <?php
        if ( $e_cart < 300 ) {
            echo "Get a free gift, when you purchase for ${e_cart_remaining} more.";
        }?>
```

So the problem is, that if a customers has goods for 250 in his cart the message will say: "Purchase for 50 more to get a free gift". (*Because you will get a free gift at 300*). But if they change the quantity of one of the products the text still says 50. (*Because the page have not updated*)

How do i trigger this script or block of code every time the cart is updated?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display a custom message on cart page based on cart amount, use the following:

```
// On cart page only
add_action( 'woocommerce_check_cart_items', 'custom_total_item_quantity_message' );
function custom_total_item_quantity_message() {
  $e_cart = WC()->cart->cart_contents_total * 1.25;
  $e_cart_remaining = 300 - $e_cart; 

    if( is_cart() &&  $e_cart < 300  ){
        wc_print_notice( sprintf( __("Get a free gift, when you purchase for %s more.", "woocommerce"), $e_cart_remaining ), 'notice' );
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).

Comment: If still any issue please let me know i am here to help you . :)